# inovke functions javascript using while

Tags: javascript, arrays

can anyone tell me what is wrong here im just try to invoke this list of functions using array and while if it's possible thanks in advance.

```
var funciones = ["basicas();", "likeFbk();", "cambiarFondo();"],
        i = 0;
while (funciones[i]) {
    funciones[i];
    i++;
}
```

jslint show this errors: 
91 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.   funciones[i]; 
92  Unexpected '++'.

Solved, I use "i += 1;" instead of "i++;" and update the list of functions treated as a string, here is the code:

```
var funciones = [basicas, likeFbk, cambiarFondo], i = 0;

    while (funciones[i]) {
        funciones[i]();
        i += 1;
    }
```

thank's guys!

Comment: Is this the updated code?

Comment: Instead of incrementing the index manually, you can just let the **while** do the job. Checkout my updated answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way (not sure what you intend to do though, i am guessing you want to iterate unless there is no value at ith index)

```
var funciones = [basicas, likeFbk, cambiarFondo], i = 0;

while (funciones[i]) 
{
    funciones[i]();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , I did not know what should be treated as a string, I learned something new today :) . jslint now just gives me this error: **92 Unexpected '++'.**

Comment: @ErickLs Happy to help.

Comment: Ignore jslint. Start using another linter.

Comment: @torazaburo problem solved changing "i++;" to "i += 1;"

Comment: @ErickLs Sure, but that is not the end of your battles with jslint's ridiculous, opinionated error messages, many of which can not even be turned off. Move on to better alternatives such as eshint.

Comment: @torazaburo are u angry with jslint xD, anyway the code func now! thanks  to all!

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke functions like that. The functions array is just a list of strings and not a list of functions. You have two ways of doing this:

1. Instead of list of strings, use list of functions as below:

   ```
   var functions = [basicas, likeFbk, cambiarFondo];
   while (i in funciones) {
        functions[i]();
   }
   ```
2. Use eval to evaluate string that contains javascript executable code:

   ```
   var funciones = ["basicas();", "likeFbk();", "cambiarFondo();"],
           i = 0;
   while (funciones[i]) {
       eval(funciones[i]);
       i++;
   }
   ```

Always go for the first approach, because the second approach is considered as evil.

Comment: thank you very much , I did not know what should be treated as a string, I learned something new today :) . jslint now just gives me this error: **92 Unexpected '++'**

Comment: Because it's also a valid solution to the given problem. And it doesn't hurt to know that there is another such solution. :)

Comment: i use the update break down me navigator D: chrome and mozilla D: 'funciones = [basicas, likeFbk, cambiarFondo], i = 0;
  while (i in funciones) {
   funciones[i]();
  }'

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer

```
var call = Function.call;
[basicas, likeFbk, cambiarFondo].forEach(call, call);
```

How this works is left as an exercise.